# Montage (Image Magic) combine pictures via script

Tags: bash, imagemagick, montage

i need a little help to MONTAGE (ImageMagic):

How to combine 300 pictures in two separated folders?

Folder A includes pictures: *a_001.png ... a_300.png*

Folder B includes pictures: *b_001.png ... b_300.png*

I would like to combine *a_001.png*  with *b_001.png*, *a_002.png*  with *b_002.png* and so on.

How to solve this problem (i have no experience in scripting). I would prefer a small bash-script (linux), if necessary.

Thanks a lot

Comment: So wil there be 300 separate output files, each with 2 images in it - one from directory A and one from directory B? Or one 300 page PDF with 2 pictures on each page? Or a 600 page TIFF file with images alternating from each directory?

Comment: What have you done so far? Post what you already did and tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
for i in $(seq -f "%03g" 1 300)
do
    montage {A,B}/{a,b}_$i.png ab_out_$i.png
done
```

What's going on...

- The `for` loop iterates from 1 to 300 with a zero-padding (e.g. `001` ... `300`)
- The `{A,B}` is a [term wildcard](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm), and will expand to..

  ```
  montage A/a_$i.png B/b_$i.png ab_out_$i.png
  ```
- Montage will write out the result to `ab_out_$i.png`.